# Azure Powershell Query to return VM details

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Im trying to write a powershell query to return the following table:

```
NAME    STATUS  RESOURCE GROUP  VMSIZE  SIZEREASON (TAG)    LOCATION    PUBLIC DNS NAME
```

I can use `Get-AzureRmVM | Select-Object Name, ResourceGroupName, Location` but when I try to add on VmSize, the column is there but without values.

If I run just `Get-AzureRmVM` then I get the VmSize, so I don't understand why I can't select it.

I also need to work out how to add in Status, SIZEREASON (TAG),PUBLIC DNS NAME

Any guidence is most appreciated.

Its also worth noting, that my table also needs to contain both Resource Managed VM's and Classic VM's (So all VM's)

***UPDATE***

My Powershell query is currently:

```
Get-AzureRmVm `
  | Select-Object ResourceGroupName `
                , Name `
                , Location `
                , @{Name="VmSize"; Expression={$_.ToPSVirtualMachine().HardwareProfile.VmSize}} `
                , @{Name="SizeReason(Tag)"; Expression={$_.ToPSVirtualMachine().Tags.Values}} `
                , FullyQualifiedDomainName `
   | Format-Table
```

The outstanding problems are:

1. FullyQualifiedDomainName does not work
2. I am also missing the status (Eg: Running, Stopped (Deallocated) etc..)

Comment: Check the output of `Get-AzureRmVM | Get-Member`

Comment: I had also done that but I can not see a property called VmSize, even though just running 'Get-AzureRmVM' gives me VmSize

Answer (score 1):

This was trickier than I expected....

```
Get-AzureRmVm | Select-Object @{Name="VmSize"; Expression={$_.ToPSVirtualMachine().HardwareProfile.VmSize}}
```

Comment: This has certianly pointed me in the right direction, it has given me what I needed for the tag too, the only thing I need to work out now is how to get the Public DNS Name in the table (FQDN), so I currently have `Get-AzureRmVm | Select-Object ResourceGroupName, Name, Location, @{Name="VmSize"; Expression={$_.ToPSVirtualMachine().HardwareProfile.VmSize}}, @{Name="SizeReason(Tag)"; Expression={$_.ToPSVirtualMachine().Tags.Values}} | Format-Table`

Comment: @Jeffrey `FullyQualifiedDomainName` is a readily available property: `Get-AzureRmVM | Get-Member | Where-Object Name -EQ FullyQualifiedDomainName`

Comment: So it is, but then running this does not return the values `Get-AzureRmVm | Select-Object ResourceGroupName, Name, Location, @{Name="VmSize"; Expression={$_.ToPSVirtualMachine().HardwareProfile.VmSize}}, @{Name="SizeReason(Tag)"; Expression={$_.ToPSVirtualMachine().Tags.Values}},  FullyQualifiedDomainName | Format-Table`

Comment: Which values? The subscription I'm tinkering in doesn't have any FQDN exposed so I can't test that bit returns correctly.

Comment: Sorry if im not being very clear. `Get-AzureRmVm | Select-Object ResourceGroupName, Name, Location, @{Name="VmSize"; Expression={$_.ToPSVirtualMachine().HardwareProfile.VmSize}}, @{Name="SizeReason(Tag)"; Expression={$_.ToPSVirtualMachine().Tags.Values}}, FullyQualifiedDomainName | Format-Table` does not provide me the FQDN, and I have also spotted that I still need to find a way to get the status (Eg: Running, Stopped (deallocated)) etc..